# Finding approximating sequence of simple functions for a particular sequence

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I want to find a sequence of simple functions $\phi_\epsilon$ and $\psi_\epsilon (x)$ for the function f,

$$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} x & x\in Q^c\cap[0,1],  \\ 0& x\in Q\cap[0,1]. \end{array} \right.$$

such that $\phi_\epsilon (x)\leq f(x) \leq \psi_\epsilon (x), \forall x\in [0,1] $ and $|\psi_\epsilon (x)-\phi_\epsilon (x)| < \epsilon$.

I tried to make a partition of the Range of f and find the sequence as left end point of subintervals of the partition to find $\phi_\epsilon$. But it is becoming complicated as the range is set of all irrationals in [0,1]and 0. This is the method from the "simple approximation lemma,Chapter 3, Real analysis(4th edition) by  H L Royden (Page number 61)".

Can someone guide me?

Comment: Find the one for $f_1(x)=x$ first.

Comment: @ArcticChar This where I am having trouble , since range is only having irrational. Can you elaborate a little bit more? It will be great help

Comment: my function $f_1(x)=x$ is much simpler. Can you find $\phi_\epsilon, \psi_\epsilon$ for $f_1$ first?

Comment: @ArcticChar yes, I am choosing the epsilon as 1/n and making a partition of the interval with each subinterval having length 1/(n+1)  and defining the simple functions according to the lemma

Comment: @ArcticChar can you please just lead me after this